# error: C compiler cannot create executables wolfssl config lib

Tags: wolfssl

i am facing issue with wolfssl configuration.
`checking for arm-none-eabi-gcc... arm-none-eabi-gcc

checking whether the C compiler works... no

configure: error: in `/home/hyd/wksp/wolfssl-5.5.4-stable':

configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables`

````
./configure: line 4493: arm-none-eabi-gcc: command not found

configure:4502: $? = 127

configure:4491: arm-none-eabi-gcc -v >&5

./configure: line 4493: arm-none-eabi-gcc: command not found

configure:4502: $? = 127```


to build the wolfssl configuration lib
````